# exiting a running command in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I'm writing a script that calls a command line tool and displays the output from the command on the screen. The issue is that after the command runs it doesn't exit on it's own, it requires manual typing of ctrl-c to stop and continue on with the rest of the python script. Does anyone know how I could get it to stop on it's own and continue on with the rest of the script?

```
cmd ='./ppshelper -sms "15062929382" warning'
os.system(cmd)
print "SMS sent"
```

"SMS sent" is not printed until the user presses ctrl-c

Thanks

Comment: The question is about ppshelper rather than Pyhton. Read its manual or ask its vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['/full/path/to/ppshelper', '-sms', '15062929382','warning'])
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! Any idea how I can get the output from p to display before the rest of the code is executed?